# why is the parameter passed to function B inside the function A when I called function A?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    window.something = (function(){
        return function(x){
        console.log(x);

        };  


    })();

    something("hello");
</script>
```

Just wondering, why is the parameter "hello" passed to the function inside the something function which has no parameter? Also, why doesn't the something function execute immediately? Its a self-invoking function but its strange that I have to call it first before it can execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: The function without the parameter is not "the something function". It's an IIFE that *returns* the `function(x) {…}` that will become `something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are directly calling the function, also known as the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

So when having this code

```
something = (function(){
    return function(myparam) {
        // ...
    };  
})();
```

it is equivalent to this code:

```
something = function(myparam) {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`something` is the result of an [immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) that returns the internal function. You then call that internal function with "hello".

Answer (score 1):

This is how closure works. You can a function and then again call the function with parameter for return function. Take a look at this example:-

```js
function multiply(num1) {
  return function(num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
  };
}

var multi = multiply(2);
console.log(multi(5));
```

Now , as you can see we stored the first function call in a variable called multi (which you can say is the function from the first return statement of the function multiply on line 2) and the using multi as a function we are passing it an argument for num2 .